# Python - AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python

I am working on a simple python client and server that can write code to a file as its sent. So far I have been stuck on this error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'

Here is the client's code:

```
# CCSP Client
# (C) Chris Dorman - 2013 - GPLv2

import socket
import sys

# Some settings
host = raw_input('Enter the Host: ')
port = 7700
buff = 24
connectionmax = 10

# Connect to server
server = socket.socket()
server.connect((host, port))

print 'Connected!'

while True:
    open_file = raw_input("File (include path): ")
    fcode = open(open_file, "rb")
    while True:
        readcode = fcode.read(buff)
        server.send(readcode)
        if not fcode:
            server.send("OK\n")
            print "Transfer complete"
            break
```

Server:

```
# CCSP Server
# (C) Chris Dorman - 2013 - GPLv2

import socket
import sys
import string
import random

def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))

host = "0.0.0.0"
port = 7700
buff = 1024
filepath = "/home/chris/"
extension = ".txt"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))

print "Server Started"


while True:
    server.listen(1)
    conn = server.accept()  
    print 'Client' + str(conn)
    print 'Generating a random file'
    filename = filepath + str(id_generator()) + extension
    fcode = open(filename, "wb")
    while True:
        if conn != 0: 
            code = conn.read(buff)
            fcode.write(buff)
            if conn == "DONE": 
                print 'Transfer complete'
                break #EOT
```

Any help with getting this to work would be awesome. I just keep getting that dumb error when it gets down to: `code = conn.read(buff)` on the servers script

Comment: `socket.accept` returns a tuple… try `help(socket)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, `accept()` returns a tuple. It looks like you want the first item in the tuple, which will be a new socket object.

Of course, sockets don't have a `read()` method either. I'm guessing that what you actually want is:

```
code = conn.recv(buff)
```

As recv() returns data that has been written to a socket's connection.

Answer (score 2):

You should read [some doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.accept). `accept()` returns a tuple not a file-like object.