# Python: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python

I'm getting an error for a program that used to work without any problem.
The folder xxx_xxx_xxx contains a lot of image files in jpeg format.

I'm trying to run through each image and retrieve hue values for each pixel on each image.

I've tried the solutions proposed here: [Python - AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713981/python-attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attribute-read) and here: [AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734167/attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attribute-read) with no success.

Code:

```
from PIL import Image
import colorsys
import os

numberofPix = 0
list = []
hueValues = 361
hueRange = range(hueValues)

for file in os.walk("c:/users/xxxx/xxx_xxx_xxx"):
    im = Image.open(file)
    width, height = im.size
    rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')

    widthRange = range(width)
    heightRange = range(height)

    for i in widthRange:
        for j in heightRange:
            r, g, b = rgb_im.getpixel((i, j))
            if r == g == b:
                continue
            h, s, v = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r/255.0, g/255.0, b/255.0)
            h = h * 360
            h = int(round(h))
            list.append(h)
            numberofPix = numberofPix + 1

for x in hueRange:
    print "Number of hues with value " + str(x) + ":" + str(list.count(x))

print str(numberofPix)
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how this code worked previously (especially if the line - `for file in os.walk("c:/users/nathan/New_Screenshots_US/Dayum"):` was there before as well) , that line is the main reason for your issue.

`os.walk` returns a tuple of the format - `(dirName, subDirs, fileNames)` - where dirName is the name of the directory currently being walked, `fileNames` is the list of files in that particular directory.

In the next line you are doing - `im = Image.open(file)` - this would not work, because `file` is a tuple (of the above format) . You need to iterate over each file name and if the file is a `.jpeg` then you need to use `os.path.join` to create the path to the file and use it in `Image.open()` .

Example -

```
from PIL import Image
import colorsys
import os
import os.path

numberofPix = 0
list = []
hueValues = 361
hueRange = range(hueValues)

for (dirName, subDirs, fileNames) in os.walk("c:/users/nathan/New_Screenshots_US/Dayum"):
    for file in fileNames:
        if file.endswith('.jpeg'):
            im = Image.open(os.path.join(dirName, file))
            . #Rest of the code here . Please make sure you indent them correctly inside the if block.
            .
```